# Facebook deep linking in android not launching play store

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook, deep-linking

I integrated facebook SDK(Version 3.22.0) for my android application sharing feeds feature. I want to use deeplinking feature for my posted feeds.

For that i followed the followed the link [Deep liking](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/link-to-your-native-app). And implemented.

My idea is to open my application when user taps on posted feed from my application if my application is installed in device. If my application is not installed feed tapping should open google play store with my application details.

Here is the current working flow:

- Application is opening if my application is installed in device.
- Opening web view with google play store with my application details if my application is not installed in device. **It is not expected**

Expected work flow is:

- It should open google play store with my application details if my application is not installed in device.

I generated Key Hashes with my local debug.keystore and product.keystore and placed them in facebook developer console for registered application. Which i am using for deep linking.

Please can anyone let me know why deep linking is not launching google play store application with my application details of my application is not installed.

Comment: What version of the Facebook app do you have? Also, it's opening the embedded webview to a play.google.com url, but is not opening the play store?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it is opening embedded webview not play store. But i need to open play store. I have downloaded facebook application from google play store. And i am using facebook SDK Version 3.22.0 to integrate in my android code.

Comment: Have you tried using App Links as documented here? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android

The docs you pointed out to seem to be an old standard.

Comment: I can't use App links it is required live web page that doesn't existed for me. I tried facebook hosting URL also. That i am not able to finish by following the facebook documentation.

Comment: You can now use a web UI to create a hosting URL rather than going through the command line: https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host

Comment: Hi @Ming Li. The link given by you is only for updating the created Host URL not for creating host url.

Comment: You can absolutely create a hosted URL with it, just fill in all the data. It ALSO allows you to modify an existing one, but if you leave that field blank, it will create one for you. I know since I wrote the tool.

Comment: in my case when facebook app installed it is redirecting me to google play store with message "Item Not Found" and when facebook app is not installed it is redirecting properly to google play store with app details.... strange behaviur